# How to extend an existing workflow in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

How can I extend an existing workflow by allowing one more rule?
In my case the workflow checks if a variable is set to a value from a set of legal options. If that's not the case, no job should be allowed to run:

```yaml
# base_workflow.yaml
workflow:
  rules: 
    - if: $JOB == "option1"
    - if: $JOB == "option2"
    - if: $JOB == "option3"

base_job:
  script:
    - # relies on legal value of $JOB
    - ...
```

I want to extend this workflow by allowing one more option:

```yaml
# my_workflow.yaml

# .gitlab-ci.yml
include:
  - local: 'base_workflow.yaml'  # Include the external workflow file

my_job:
  script:
    - echo "This is my job"
  rules:
   - if: $JOB == "my_option"
```

This way the example does not work because the workflow doesn't allow a `$JOB` value of `"my_option"` and there is no way to extend the original workflow.

How can I achieve this without repeating the list from `base_workflow.yaml` (which may change) in `my_workflow.yaml`
and without allowing the workflow to run if an illegal value for `$JOB` is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the [`!reference` tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags) to achieve your goal.

In your `base_workflow.yaml` define your default rules:

```yaml
# base_workflow.yaml
.default_rules:
  rules:
    - if: $JOB == "option1"
    - if: $JOB == "option2"
    - if: $JOB == "option3"

workflow:
  rules: 
    - !reference [.default_rules, rules]

base_job:
  script:
    - # relies on legal value of $JOB
    - ...
```

Your `my_workflow.yaml` file will be:

```yaml
# my_workflow.yaml

# .gitlab-ci.yml
include:
  - local: 'base_workflow.yaml'  # Include the external workflow file

workflow:
  rules: 
    - if: $JOB == "my_option"
    - !reference [.default_rules, rules]

my_job:
  script:
    - echo "This is my job"
```

If the `!reference` tags don't work you will have to redefine your workflow in `my_workflow.yaml` with all the rules you need.

EDIT by OP: the `!reference` tag solution works! even though it gets expanded to:

```
workflow:
  rules:
  - if: $JOB == "my_option"
  - - if: $JOB == "option1"
    - if: $JOB == "option2"
    - if: $JOB == "option3"
```